# RegEx for replacing a string if it contains more than 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this user price input that I want to allow 0, 1 or 2 decimal digits.

- I'm using comma for decimals.
- I'm not using nor allowing thousand separators.

**QUESTION:**

I want to replace the input if the user enters a third decimal digit.

Somethin like:

- `5` this is ok
- `5,` this is ok, because it's waiting for the decimals
- `5,5` this is ok
- `5,55` this is ok
- `5,555` this is NOT OK, and I want to delete the last digit and go back to `5,55`
- `5,555555555555` this is also NOT OK, the user might paste something with extra decimal digits and I want to trim them down to 2 decimals maximum, going back again to `5,55`

How can I do this?

I know how I can match the end of the string: `/[,\d+]$/`

But how can I replace with the first two digits after the comma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your pattern `[,\d+]$` will match a comma a digit or a plus sign and assert the end of the string.

You could capture in a group 1+ digits,  an optional comma and 0-2 digits. then match 0+ digits afterwards and replace with group 1.

```
^(\d+,?\d{0,2})\d*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of strig
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+` 1+ digits
  - `,?` optional comma
  - `\d{0,2}` 0 - 2 digits
- `)` Close group
- `\d*` Match 0+ digits
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nq391V/1)

If you want to keep the part before the decimal, you could use a capturing group`^(\d+),?\d{0,2}$` and replace with the first capturing group:

```js
[
  "5",
  "5",
  "5,0",
  "5,00",
  "5,000"
].forEach(s => console.log(s.replace(/^(\d+,?\d{0,2})\d*$/, "$1")));
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I use that match to replace my string and get rid of the extra decimals?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio I think you are missing the `^`

Comment: Should I use `String​.prototype​.match()` ?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio That is because of the anchors `^` and `$` I am assuming the OP want to match only those matches.

Comment: @cbdev420 You could replace with the first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/Nq391V/2

Comment: @cbdev420 I have added an example with replace.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't very clear. On your example I only would change the `5,000`, that I would turn into `5,00`. Anything above two decimals should go back to 2.

Comment: @cbdev420 I see, I have updated the pattern and the demo.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could always temporarily convert the comma to a period, parse the float and fix it to 2 decimals, then replace the period with a comma again like below;

```js
let str = '1,567895'; // price value

let val = parseFloat(str.replace(',', '.')).toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
console.log(val);
```

Comment: It works! But I'm looking to solve this by manipulating the string only. Thanks.

Comment: @cbdev420 No worries, makes sense! However, note that once you have the right amount of numbers, you'll have to deal with rounding and if you're using this as a price, converting a number with no decimals (i.e, 5) back in to 5,00.